# how to create accurate collision for 3d meshes? (ios arkit or realitykit)

Tags: ios, arkit, realitykit

i want to use `arview.scene.raycast(origin: SIMD3<Float>, direction: SIMD3<Float>` to hit 3d model,
use `generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)` to generate box collision
**the problem is** : i want to hit model'surface,so is there a way to **create accurate collision**

[image: the red line is model's collision]

*i'm use arkit and realitykit  **not** scenekit*

Answer (score 8):

Using `generateCollisionShapes(recursive: Bool)` generate a very simple box as the CollisionComponent. 
In order to create an accurate collision body that represents the chair, you need to use the mesh of the model as its CollisionComponent:

```
yourModelEntity.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: yourModelEntity.model!.mesh)]
```

An even more efficient approach would be to create a lower poly version of the model and use that as its CollisionComponent.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let  model = arView.scene.findEntity(named: name) as? ModelEntity {

            if let m = model.model {
                model.components[CollisionComponent] =  CollisionComponent(shapes: [ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: m.mesh)])
            }

        }
```